# Simple search in a MySQL DB

Tags: php, sql, search, mysql

I have a problem in creating a search script in mysql database. I tried many scripts but I failed. What I want to do is something like this:

The database has a table, 2 columns (CODE, ID)

In the search bar enter a maximum of 20 digit CODE format and script display ID ( max. 5 digits ) of the code. All this in a single web page, preferably. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add the code you've written, and let us know why it's failing?

Comment: I'm seeing that a lot lately: `I tried many scripts but I failed`...

Comment: add some codes and ask whats wrong...???

Comment: What is the error you get? Please check your log files for errors and report back so we can help you, or just google it for you. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by like a example is below

```
 $query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE   CODE LIKE '%{$each}%' OR ID LIKE '%{$each}%'";
```